# Automate Login / Surf and Download File on criteria using Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, authentication, phantomjs

I've been trying to do this since a long time.
[PHANTOMJS VERSION] => 2.1.1
My goal is to log in a portal, go to different menu after being logged, insert parameters to research available file, download file if not downloaded yet.
Problem is that I can login to the portal and reach the index page but when I click on the tag "a" which is the one button that bring me to the new form to fill for searching file, it bring me back to loginpage ... Dunno why that happend. If I use this script in chrome dev it works fine ...

LOGIN SUCCESFUL
[image]

REDIRECTED TO LOGIN PAGE
[image]
 This is my code:

```
<pre><code>var page = require('webpage').create();
var system= require('system');
var loadInProgress = false;
var testindex = 0;
var address;
var pos;
var stringa;



// Route "console.log()" calls from within the Page context to the main Phantom context (i.e. current "this")
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};


page.onError = function(msg, trace) {

  var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];

  if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
      msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));
    });
  }

  console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

page.onAlert = function(msg) {
    console.log('alert!!> ' + msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("CARICAMENTO PAGINA INIZIATO"); //*Page started loading*
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    loadInProgress = false;
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Caricamento pagina fallito !'); //*Page failed to load*
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        console.log("CARICAMENTO PAGINA COMPLETATO"); //*Page loading complete*
        page.render("foto" + testindex + ".png");//*Screen Capture*
        console.log("Foto effettuata"); 
        var sitoattuale= page.evaluate(function(){
            return window.location.href;
        });
        console.log(sitoattuale);
    }
};

var steps = [
    function() {
        page.open(system.args[1]);
    },

    function() {


        page.evaluate(function() {
                    //*insert username and password and click the button to submit the form*
                    document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtUser").value="MYUSERNAME";
                    document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtPSW").value="MYPASSWORD";
                    document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_btnLogin").click();


        });
                //*Capture inserted credentials*
        page.render("credenziali.png")
    },
        function() {

        page.evaluate(function(){
            var a=document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenun16Items");
            var b= a.getElementsByTagName("a");
            var c= b[0];
            c.click();
        });


                //*Capture click of the button that brings me to the form where I ve to insert parameters for the search*
        page.render("Cliccato_ricerca.png")

    },

    function() {
        //*I capture the screen as I should be to the form page but it caputre the login page unfilled*
        page.render("ramomisura.png")
        console.log("stouscendo");

    }
];interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        if (testindex==0){
            console.log("Fase " + (testindex+1) + " : Avvio portale");
        }else{
            if(testindex==1){
                console.log("Fase " + (testindex+1) + " : Loing in corso ...");
            }else{
                if(testindex==2){
                    console.log("Fase " + (testindex+1) + " : Tentativo di navigazione al ramo misure ...")
                    }else{
                        console.log("Fase " + (testindex+1) + " : Termine Programma");
                    }   
                }
            }
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("Programma Terminato");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 100)
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question is poorly researched and in the current version is more suited for a rent-a-coder site rather than SO.

Comment: Then using the same script and changing the url to http://testforum.yetanotherforum.net/login?returnurl=%2f using testbot as username and testbot123 as password ? The must be something really not working in the code ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you said in the latest comment, but *something* is most likely not working in your code, yes.